# Why Postgres SQL function scans partitions that it should not

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have stumbled upon very weird issue with my SQL functions. They appear to have different execution plans between function `language SQL` and `language plpgsql` but I cannot tell what execution plan is set for `SQL` version, since it requires this: `Function's final statement must be SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.` and won't let me use `EXPLAIN`.

As for why I know they have different plans, it is because `SQL` version fails to execute, complaining it cannot connect to one of the foreign servers that is currently taken down. Connection is done using foreign tables and that table is partitioned by date (column `date_col`) with some of its partitions being physically on the same server and some on foreign. Date parameter used in function makes sure it should only scan one partition and that partition is on the same server. This is also shown in `explain` below used on `plain SQL` (not in function):

```
Append  (cost=2.77..39.52 rows=2 width=36)
  CTE ct
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.51 rows=100 width=4)
  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.25..2.26 rows=1 width=32)
          ->  CTE Scan on ct  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=36)
        Filter: ((date_col = '2017-07-30'::date) AND (some_col = ANY ($1)))
  ->  Seq Scan on "part$_table1_201707"  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=1 width=36)
        Filter: ((date_col = '2017-07-30'::date) AND (some_col = ANY ($1)))
```

Foreign partitions are before year 2017 and it shows that planner chooses correct partition and does not bother scanning any others. This is true for `plain SQL` and `plpgsql function` but not for `sql function`. Why could that be and can I avoid it without rewriting my functions?

From what I figured, there must be some difference between how parameters are passed in `SQL function`, since hard coding date in it prevents query from scanning unnecessary partitions. Maybe something like that happens:

```
WITH ct AS (SELECT unnest(array[1,2]) AS arr)
  SELECT col1, col2
    FROM table1
   WHERE date_col = (SELECT '2017-07-30'::date)
     AND some_col = ANY((SELECT array_agg(arr) FROM ct)::int[])
```

Producing such `EXPLAIN`:

```
Append  (cost=2.78..183.67 rows=3 width=36)
  CTE ct
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.51 rows=100 width=4)
  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4)
  InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
    ->  Aggregate  (cost=2.25..2.26 rows=1 width=32)
          ->  CTE Scan on ct  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on table1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=36)
        Filter: ((date_col = $1) AND (some_col = ANY ($2)))
  ->  Seq Scan on "part$_table1_201707"  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=1 width=36)
        Filter: ((date_col = $1) AND (some_col = ANY ($2)))
  ->  Foreign Scan on "part$_table1_201603"  (cost=100.00..144.14 rows=1 width=36)
```

For the reference, you can reproduce issue on PostgreSQL 9.6.4 using code below:

```
CREATE SERVER broken_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host 'broken_server', dbname 'postgres',
         port '5432');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER broken_server 
OPTIONS (user 'foreign_username', password 'foreign_password');

CREATE TABLE table1 (id serial PRIMARY KEY, date_col date,
                     some_col int, col1 int, col2 text);

CREATE TABLE part$_table1_201707 ()
INHERITS (table1);
ALTER TABLE part$_table1_201707 ADD CONSTRAINT part$_table1_201707_date_chk
        CHECK (date_col BETWEEN '2017-07-01'::date AND '2017-07-31'::date);

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE part$_table1_201603 ()
INHERITS (table1) SERVER broken_server
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'part$_table1_201603');
ALTER TABLE part$_table1_201603 ADD CONSTRAINT part$_table1_201603_date_chk
        CHECK (date_col BETWEEN '2016-03-01'::date AND '2016-03-31'::date);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_plpgsql(param1 date, param2 int[])
 RETURNS TABLE(col1 int, col2 text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
BEGIN
  --
  RETURN QUERY
  WITH ct AS (SELECT unnest(param2) AS arr)
  SELECT t.col1, t.col2
    FROM table1 AS t
   WHERE date_col = param1
     AND some_col = ANY((SELECT array_agg(arr) FROM ct)::int[]); --reasons
  --
END;
$function$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_sql(param1 date, param2 int[])
 RETURNS TABLE(col1 int, col2 text)
 LANGUAGE SQL
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
  --
  WITH ct AS (SELECT unnest(param2) AS arr)
  SELECT t.col1, t.col2
    FROM table1 AS t
   WHERE date_col = param1
     AND some_col = ANY((SELECT array_agg(arr) FROM ct)::int[])
  --
$function$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_sql_hardcoded(param1 date, param2 int[])
 RETURNS TABLE(col1 int, col2 text)
 LANGUAGE SQL
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
  --
  WITH ct AS (SELECT unnest(param2) AS arr)
  SELECT t.col1, t.col2
    FROM table1 AS t
   WHERE date_col = '2017-07-30'::date
     AND some_col = ANY((SELECT array_agg(arr) FROM ct)::int[])
  --
$function$;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM function_sql('2017-07-30'::date, array[1,2]);
-- ERROR: could not connect to server "broken_server"

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM function_plpgsql('2017-07-30'::date, array[1,2]);
--works

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM function_sql_hardcoded('2017-07-30'::date, array[1,2]);
--works, but useless
```

Comment: any news on this?..

Comment: I decided to report this as a bug on pgsql-bugs@postgresql.org but nothing so far. I'll go ahead and post it as a question on -general if nothing happens today.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

> Constraint exclusion only works when the query's WHERE clause contains
>   constants (or externally supplied parameters). For example, a
>   comparison against a non-immutable function such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
>   cannot be optimized, since the planner cannot know which partition the
>   function value might fall into at run time.

that would explain scanning unnecessary partitions - plpgsql processes query before giving it to optimyzer I assume, and sql function with constant should work. as well as prepared statement I guess. but comparing attribute value to function parameter is probably not the suitable case :)

Comment: Function parameter surely qualify as `externally supplied parameters`? I have tested prepared statement and it works as expected, so why wouldn't SQL function work the same way?

Comment: please - don't think I know the answer - I just found closest quote from docs :) I assume though that both prepared statement and return query first parse and replace param1 with actual value before presenting it to optimyzer, which does not happen in SQL function case. I assume people who participated in coding will answer your question

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if I should have posted my question on dba. or Postgres mailing list instead since it seems to be issue with Postgres internal workings and only its devs would know for sure. I was hoping tho that someone else had similar issue and there might be server parameter that would easily take care of it.

Comment: I see Laurenz Albe and Craig Ringer quite often answering postgres tag here - they both seen between Postgres devs :) so the chances are. btw if you get answer in IRC or mailing list, please post it here as well - very interesting.